# What is the structure of the .raw exported blockchain file like?

Tags: blockchain-export

The monero-blockchain-export tool allows one to export the blockchain as a .raw file. My question is, what does the structure of the file like, and what are some of the tools that can be used to interact with it and explore the data? Pardon my naiveté, but .raw file formats usually refer to photographic files, so what kind of tools would open a .raw file that is not a photo?

Comment: Just for giggles I'd try tossing it into binwalk.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a binary (raw) version of the blockchain that can be imported using `monero-blockchain-import`. To my knowledge the only tool that can read this file is `monero-blockchain-import`.

The file extension is immaterial.